Most efficient way to test Lithium(LMO) cell capacity/ bad cells
I am wondering what is the most efficient way to test Lithium Ion cells, specifically LMO, to tell which ones are failing or are near their end of life.
I have a plug in hybrid, which I have torn apart, and want to know which cells are good and which ones I should replace. They are prismatic cells and are 15 Ah. I have two chargers and one discharger along with multiple multimeters and basic electronics stuff. Does anyone have a good testing procedure? I just don't want this to take 18 days to do. The only way I know is to charge and discharge to see how many Ah they hold, but at 5 A this takes 5 hours each.

You're correct that it will take many days to do the capacity test. There is no easy workaround because you're limited by the power of your charge and of your discharger. The only way to speed up cell-level testing is by working in parallel with multiple chargers and dischargers. Or by working in series by bulk-charging the battery with a high-voltage/high-power charger and bulk-discharging the battery with a high-voltage/high-power discharger.
But you're missing an equally crucial test: cell resistance. All too often, the cell capacity is acceptable, but the vehicle stalls during acceleration because a cell has too high a resistance, resulting in an excessive voltage drop under load.
To test the resistance of a cell, measure the open circuit voltage, the voltage under a heavy load, and the current into that load. The resistance is (V-unloaded - V-loaded) / I-load. You don't know what resistance should be considered too high, but you can at least spot some outliers.

Got it. I have been recording that voltage under a 5A load. Do you think I should do a higher amperage? I was doing Voltage before, Voltage when load applied, and Voltage 1 minute after 5A load.
